# Node.js Multiple Mysql Queries

Tags: mysql, node.js

I am coding user register form. In node-js [node mysql plugin](https://github.com/felixge/node-mysql), do I have to write nested codes like this?

```
var query1 = connection.query('SELECT * FROM table1 WHERE var1 = ?', [var1], function(err, results1) {

    if(results1[0]) {
        var query2 = connection.query('SELECT * FROM table2 WHERE var2 = ?', [var2], function(err, results2) {

            if(results2[0]) {
                var query3 = connection.query('SELECT * FROM table2 WHERE var3 = ?', [var3], function(err, results3) {

                    if(results3[3]) {
                        // do it.
                    }

                });
            }

        });
    }

});
```

To write nested codes is really boring. Is there a way like this to do multiple queries?

```
var query1 = connection.query('SELECT * FROM table1 WHERE var1 = ?', [var1], function(err, results1) {  });
var query2 = connection.query('SELECT * FROM table1 WHERE var2 = ?', [var2], function(err, results2) {  });
var query3 = connection.query('SELECT * FROM table1 WHERE var3 = ?', [var3], function(err, results3) {  });

if(results1[0]) {

} else if(results2[0]) {

} else if(results3[0]) {

} else {
    // do it.
}
```

Answer (score 0):

A common solution to these kinds of problems is to use a utility module like [async](https://github.com/caolan/async). For your particular situation, you might use something like [async.waterfall](https://github.com/caolan/async#waterfall).

Comment: I didnt ask async problem... I just asked is to write nested code necessary like first block

Comment: And my answer was that you don't *have* to write nested code like that and that `async` is one alternative to writing nested anonymous function.

Comment: Thank you. Well, Is there a other way?